# Is there a way to include a hyperlink within SQL to Jump to a certain section of code?

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a CTE Query that is involving quite a few Tables.  Is there a way to create a hyperlink at the top of the Query to auto jump to a specific table to test or debug?

Comment: How exactly do you make a query jump to a specific table?

Comment: That'd be an editor feature of whatever you're using to write those queries; it's not something the SQL Server engine is concerned about. SSMS has no such thing, as far as I know. You can, of course, always stick in a comment of some specific form (`-- Boo!` / `/* Boo! */`) and search on it.

Comment: That was my thinking too... I just wanted to be sure.  Thanks for the replies :)

Answer (score 0):

There's not that exact functionality in SSMS. However, you can use Bookmarks to navigate through different parts of the code. Using `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+K` will add or remove a bookmark and you can navigate using `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+N` for the following bookmark or `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+P` for the previous one.

There's of course the GOTO statement for code to use some sort of links to labels, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by your last sentence -- [`GOTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql) certainly is a statement in T-SQL, but it has nothing at all to do with hyperlinks. Unless that's a fancy new name for "label" that I've never heard of.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got distracted and didn't proof read my answer which became sort of confusing.

Comment: Thank you Luis! I have added the bookmarks and it works quite nicely!